# Question on how to sample randomly from the given distribution

Tags: sampling, random-generation, chi-squared-distribution

I have following distribution which looks as follows:

$P\left(\kappa| u,v,\lambda,y\right) \propto \kappa^{-\frac{n}{2}}exp\left\{-\cfrac{1}{2\kappa}\left[\epsilon + (u_1-u_2)^2 + (u_2-u_3)^2 \right]
\right\}
$

I want to generate samples from above distribution.
This distribution is also referred to in article, :

> BAYESIAN IMAGE RESTORATION,WITH TWO APPLICATIONS IN SPATIAL STATISTICS, by Julian Besag et. al. Page 9, equation 4.6

The author proposes to sample via using standard chi-square distributions. I am not sure how to do above. The standard chi-square distribution looks as follows (a bit different from above):
$P\left(\kappa\right) \propto \kappa^{\frac{n}{2}}exp\left\{-\kappa/2
\right\}$.
My questions is, given the structure of the distribution in beginning, is it ok to sample from chi-square distribution with n degrees of freedom?
Or shall I assume it to be same as Inverse Gamma with parameters:

$\alpha = \cfrac{n}{2} - 1, \beta = \cfrac{\left[\epsilon + (u_1-u_2)^2 + (u_2-u_3)^2 \right]}{2}$,

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us what aspect of sampling from this distribution you are unsure about.

Comment: Sure, the research article suggested that above can be sampled using methods for sampling from Chi-Square distribution. The form of the distribution looks similar to inverse chi-square. Therefore, I was wondering if it is ok to sample from Chi-Square with n degrees of freedom and then take an inverse of the same. Or shall I sample from inverse gamma distribution with parameters that I specified above (in the edited question).

Comment: The two approaches are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I will sample from Inverse gamma. Looks like R has some package to do the same.